# AS3 Array issue and Arduino

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

i am hoping someone can help me with a issue i am having with my AS3 script, i am new to it and apologizes if there is a simple answer

```
import flash.net.Socket;
import flash.events.Event;

var mysocket:Socket = new Socket();
    mysocket.connect("127.0.0.1",5331);;

mysocket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketDataHandler);

 var buffer:String = "";

function socketDataHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void
{

    var str:String = String(mysocket.readUTFBytes(mysocket.bytesAvailable));

    var array:Array = new Array();

buffer += str;

array = buffer.split(",");

var textpwm:Array = new Array;
var textpercentage:Array = new Array;
var textvoltage:Array = new Array;

textpwm.push(array[0]);
textpercentage.push(array[1]);
textvoltage.push(array[2]);

var pwm_a:String;
    pwm_a = textpwm.join("");
var percentage_a:String;
    percentage_a = textpercentage.join("");
var voltage_a:String;
    voltage_a = textvoltage.join("");

pwmbox.text = pwm_a;
percentagebox.text = percentage_a + "%";
voltagebox.text = voltage_a + "V";

trace(textpwm);

}
```

This is my code from my AS3 script i have tried to debug the code and have found out that my arrays

```
var textpwm:Array = new Array;
var textpercentage:Array = new Array;
var textvoltage:Array = new Array;
```

always hold the same values even when new data is sent from my arduino my array known as "array" does change as the new values come in however the others just keep the same data over and over again

if anyone can help that would be great

thank you

Comment: What's the type of information you are getting from the sockets? What is `array[0]` in `textpwm.push(array[0])`? Because if it is an Array (as you later on use `textpwm.join("");`, then it's normal to see that `textpwm = Array`..

Comment: the type of information i am getting from the socket is something like this 100,30,4, and of course the values change like this 1000,200,5, however in those arrays  in the values just stay the same 100,30,4, and don't change as the information comes in. array[0] is holding the first value of the string coming in for example 100

Comment: im using textpwm.join(""); to convert it to a string so i can display the data in my dynamic text box

Comment: Well first try to use `trace` and check what is the info coming from the Arduino! :) Is it the same every time or no? And about the string - **don't use arrays**, just use `String(array[0])`. p.s. *if* there is a lot of info, the socket will buffer rather than send the full package, if you need help with this just tell me

Comment: Are you each time sending comepletely new data from your arduino? I see you creating new array each time so `trace(textpwm);` will allways give the same as `trace(array[0])`.

Comment: i am sending new data each time from the arduino

Answer (score 0):

"buffer" is a global variable (every time when you call buffer += str; you will add a new data after existing one) so use `buffer = str;` instead of += OR `array = str.split(",");` 
 You can also remove a lot of code, with something like: `pwmbox.text = array[0] + " V;"` as an example;

[+= addition assignment](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#addition_assignment) 
 [Variables](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9d.html)